# An 'if constexpr branch' does not get discarded inside lambda that is inside a template function

Tags: c++, c++17, if-constexpr

The following [code](https://godbolt.org/z/EIPYlS):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct X {
    static constexpr void x() {}
};

template <class T1, class T2>
constexpr bool makeFalse() { return false; }

template <class T>
void foo() {
    T tmp;
    auto f = [](auto type) {
        if constexpr (makeFalse<T, decltype(type)>()) {
            T::x(); // <- clang does not discard
        } else {
            // noop
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    foo<int>();
}
```

does not compile with Clang, but compiles with GCC. I can't see anything wrong with this code, but I'm not sure. Is Clang right not compiling it?

Comment: worth mentioning that `T` is not dependant on the lambda template parameter. Don't know however how `if constexpr` should handle that.

Comment: (somewhat) equivalent example  without lambda compiles fine , so I suspect it's a clang bug https://godbolt.org/z/Xok1wC

Comment: @bolov if you remove the generic lambda, it compiles too: https://godbolt.org/z/xoTBT6

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[[stmt.if]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.if#2.sentence-3):

> During the instantiation of an enclosing templated entity, if the condition is not value-dependent after its instantiation, the discarded substatement (if any) is not instantiated.

Since `makeFalse<T, decltype(type)>()` *is* value-dependent after the instantiation of `foo<int>`, it appears that `T::x()` should be instantiated per the standard, and since `T::x` is ill-formed when `T` is `int`, Clang is right not compiling it.

Comment: Wouldn't this reasoning imply that a hypothetical `if constexpr (makeFalse<decltype(type)>) { type.x(); }` would not be discarded either?

Comment: @Barry Yes. But `type.x()` is a dependent and possibly valid expression after the instantiation.

Comment: I think "possibly valid" is muddling things, I don't think that's relevant necessarily. Are you saying it won't be discarded even if `makeFalse<decltype(type)>` is `false`? Assume it's actually an interesting check... more like `if constexpr (can_x<decltype(type)>) { type.x(); }`

Comment: I am not convinced.  Why then are my example and Amadeus compiling?

Comment: @Barry Let me try to clarify. There are two instantiations that can be involved: (1) the instantiation of `foo` (2) the instantiation of `f`'s function call operator template (which does not happen in OP's example). (1) does not discard either branch, because the condition is still value-dependent after it. If either branch is ill-formed after (1), an error will occur (but [\[temp.res\]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8) may kick in when an expression in a branch is dependent). (2) _does_ discard one branch because the condition is no longer dependent.

Comment: @cpplearner Ah, perfect, there we go, that's what I was missing. Do you mind editing that into the answer? Effectively, clang is right to reject due to [temp.res]/8 but gcc is equally fine to accept because it's ill-formed ndr.

Comment: This is equivalent to the motivating example of [P0588R0](https://wg21.link/P0588R0), except that there's not even an implicit capture that could complicate things under the old rules.